# Python Tkinter, Label has some indention?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a simple gui in tkinter using Pycharm. I have not worked with python that much but know more in java.

anyway, in my code I have made a window, root = Tk(), in that a frame packed with fill=BOTH and expand=1. in that frame I have two Labels. both have same font, different font size.
Both are added to grid, one in row=0, column=0, the other row=1, column=0.
So, the first shows up where I want it, the second one, indented to the right for some reason I can not fathom. It is under the first label as I wish but it is spaced away from the left side a little bit.

the following is my code.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()
root.title("SLIME QUEST")
root.iconbitmap("C:/Users/wolfg/Pictures/slimeIcon_edited.ico")
root.geometry("1280x720+100+1")
root.resizable(False, False)

frameMain = Frame(root, highlightthickness=0, borderwidth=0, padx=3, pady=3, bg="#99ccff")
frameMain.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

locLbl = Label(frameMain, text="Pleasant Plains", bg="#99ccff", fg="#FFFFFF", font=("Courier New", 24))
locLbl.grid(row=0, column=0)
bioLbl = Label(frameMain, text="Biome: Plains", bg="#99ccff", fg="#FFFFFF", font=("Courier New", 16))
bioLbl.grid(row=1, column=0)

mainloop()
```

Comment: The width of column 0 is being set by the wider of your two labels - and then both labels are being centered in that width, by default.  Give them both a `sticky='w'` option to align them to the left side of the column.

Comment: Thank you kindly I will try that now. I was thinking the first label was somehow effecting the second, but I did not consider the length of the text.

Comment: Yes, it has worked. Thanks again.